# How to send files to Chatfuel through Zapier using JSON API?

Tags: zapier, chatfuel

These are the steps in the Zap I have created:
1. Setup a webhook on Zapier to catch the JSON POST from Chatfuel.
2. Create a Javascript and specify the url of the file as a JSON object. (see attached file)
3. Setup a POST webhook from Zapier to post on Chatfuel.

I am stuck in step 3. I understand that Chatfuel cannot process raw JSON and the values returned need to assigned to a specific attribute. 
Any suggestions how to go ahead with it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4ljq.png)

Comment: please add relevant details, attached file?
It will be helpful if you can share your project relevant codes as well...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? More information will help here.

In lieu of that information, here are links to the Chatfuel apps on Zapier that you could use instead of Webhooks.

https://zapier.com/apps/chatfuel-for-facebook/integrations

https://zapier.com/apps/chatfuel-for-telegram/integrations

https://blog.chatfuel.com/our-zapier-app-is-now-official/